# Reference data from cell then timestamp it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I am currently using Sheetgo to timestamp data.  Unfortunately my trial is about to expire.  I'm assuming a script with a trigger would provide me with the same results, but I am unsure how to go about it.

I am pulling the value "A1" from an api:
[image]

Sheetgo then logs the value every hour on a separate sheet: [image]

Any assistance with creating a script/trigger that could perform this task would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Logging a value every hour

```
function getA1() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//wherever the data is
  const A1 = sh.getRange("A1").getValue();//wherever the data is
  ss.getSheetByName("log").appendRow([A1,new Date()]);
}
```

Run the following atleast once

```
function ctrig() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "getA1").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("getA1").timeBased().everyHours(1).create();
  }
}
```

[Script App newTrigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newTrigger(String))

Comment: Awesome. Ill give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: I'm having an issue with the trigger. I ran the script at 0200, it logs that time, but it will run again at a random interval. Second time it ran at 0220 then 0320 then 0420 etc.. any idea why thay may be?